# .off() not clearing any event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Here's the code:

```
.on(clickEvent, 'button', function() {
  console.log(Date());
})
.one(clickEvent, '.js-clear-all-actions', function() {
  _(this)
  .off()
  .unbind()
  .on(clickEvent, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  .displayLoading(0);
})
```

HTML:

```
<button class="large-button expand af-non-animated  js-prevent-double-click" type="submit">
</button>
```

trying to clear everything that is bound but even the event just bound before is still there. Please note: I'm purposedly avoiding to just add attribute disabled, so please I'd just like to make `.off()` work.

Comment: I believe `.off()` requires a parameter of event name in string. Eg., `.off("click")`. Correct me if I am wrong. It just acts like `.unbind()`. Are you sure you are doing the right one?

Comment: in theory if you don't specify any argument it should wipe everything, I tried that too btw

Comment: Can you share the html that this is supposed to interact with? It could help verifying the selectors (even though they are simple).

Comment: Can you add the html with class "js-clear-all-actions"?

Comment: and... sorry about that i think i can close the topic. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try this man:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZMbe?editors=1010

```
$("#theButton").one("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      console.log(Date());
   });
```

If your end goal is to have the button being clicked only once, that might fix your problem. Let me know :)